# I am running protractor on a chromebook : the error message tells me error:cannot find Chrome Binary?

Tags: protractor

While attempting to run protractor i get an error where it cant find chrome binary. Its a chromebook so the binary should already exist right?
why am i getting this error ?

Been looking around there doesnt seem to be any info.

```
[23:57:28] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[23:57:28] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[23:57:29] E/launcher - unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'penguin', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.44-04933-g0fb17cd4e23f', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5bad641316e9 <unknown>

[23:57:29] E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'penguin', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.19.44-04933-g0fb17cd4e23f', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: #0 0x5bad641316e9 <unknown>

    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at createDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
    at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
[23:57:29] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

Comment: I have not tried to run Protractor tests on Chromebook. We usually ensure that this works on Linux, Mac and Windows. Although Chromebooks are a Linux OS type, I'm not sure how this would work.

Comment: I was surfing the web and I found out about a software called Wine that lets you run windows programs on unix-like operating systems. Could I use that to install chrome.exe since chromebooks don't have exe files and then reference that as the binary location???

Comment: I don't know about this one. Was the idea to use directConnect? Do you have java installed on your chromebook? If you do figure this out, let me know. I'm definitely interested. If I have time, I'll try this out on my Chromebook.

Comment: Yes I was able to install java . I was using selenium web-driver.  I haven't had time to try it out these day.

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for chrome browser to run the test. In windows and Mac , if you have chrome  browser version, which you are passing in protractor capability,  installed in your system, then test run on it by default.

But You can set the chrome binary path as desired also by adding below property in your protractor.conf.js file

"chromeOptions": {
      binary: 'Path_to_Chrome_binaries',
      args: [], 
      extensions: [], 
    }

Note, binary: 'Path_to_Chrome_binaries' , here 'Path_to_Chrome_binaries' should be the path to Chrome.exe

You also need to make sure the webdriver-manager version is compatible with the chrome browser you are using to tun your test upon.

If this does not solves your issue then please provide the protractor.conf.js file while will help in answering rh2 question/debughing the issue.

Comment: I found out that chromebooks don't have a chrome.exe file check out my comment above I explain a little more some research I did.